# Окончание слова после союзов "и" и "или"

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Скажите пожалуйста какое из следующих предложений верное:

1. Could употребляется в главной части условных предложений 2 и 3 типа
2. Could употребляется в главной части условных предложений 2 и 3 типов
3. Could употребляется в главной части условных предложений 2 или 3
   типа
4. Could употребляется в главной части условных предложений 2 или 3
   типов

И как правильно заменить числа ?

1. второго или третьего
2. вторых или третьих

Comment: Задайте свой вопрос здесь:  http://english.stackexchange.com/     Здесь отвечают на вопросы по русскому языку.

Comment: @Серж Я про русский :)

Comment: Прошу вернуть на русский язык.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Скажите пожалуйста какое из следующих предложений верное:

Грамматически верны все. Выбор союза зависит от общего стиля текста, по сути дела в быту они значат одно и то же, проблемы с союзами возникают в основном у юристов и математиков. На языке теории  множеств это легко объяснить, но здесь я не буду этим заниматься. Думаю, для общего понимания союз "И" здесь более уместен.

Что же касается выбора грамматического числа, то то тут надо руководствоваться соображением смыслового единства - чем оно полнее,  тем вернее будет использовать единственное число во всех случаях. И тоже в зависимости от стиля: объясняется ли по тексту все на примере - как на представителе общей идеи - или на общих рассуждениях.

И наконец, чтение "вторых и третьих" (пусть даже тип**ов**), здесь не проходит по смыслу. Вот если бы типов с каждым номером было больше одного (ну там 2a, 2b, etc), и каждый бы считался вторым-третьим, то подобное бы еще было как-то грамматически оправдано, но в это как-то не верится.

Руководствуясь этим, я бы окончательно выбрал из предложенного:

*Could употребляется в главной части условных предложений **второго и третьего типа.***

А может быть даже и "условное предложение" поставил бы в единственное число, но это уже как вариант.

Answer (score 0):

*И*, в отличие от *или*, объединяет перечисляемые. Поэтому, верно будет — *2 и 3-го типа* и *2 или 3-го типов*.